# Handle blank values for object type column

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with excel data. I have few columns in my data frame df which are object type and have blank values. I want to write a code which can replace all the blank values in any column of df with "NA". How can I do this using pandas? Can this also be done using applymap?

Below are the column types:

```
id                           object
name                         object
year_founded                float64
city                         object
country                      object
type                         object

dtype: object
```

Sample data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['apple_inc'],'name':['Apple Inc'],'year_founded':[],'city'
:[],'country':['US'],'type':[]})
```

Comment: `df.replace('', 'NA')` or you can try this when reading your Excel file: `df = pd.read_excel(file_name, na_values=[''])`

Comment: I wish it was so simple. It doesn't work.

Comment: can you provide a reproducible sample data set?

Comment: @MaxU Updated the question

Comment: I am just curiosity about your sample data, why the value for each column is a list, not a scalar? How you store the data in your excel?

Answer (score 2):

There are two places to handle `na` values.

One is when you load the file, [pd.read_excel](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) provide parametes that handle `na` values, e.g., `na_values`.

```
pd.read_excel(file, na_values=['', ' '])
```

Another one is Pandas [miss data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html) provides some functions to handle `na` values, e.g., `replace`, `fillna` and etc.

```
df.replace('', np.nan)
```

One more thing you need to note is what your blank values extracly are, they may be '', or ' ', or '\t' and more. If you are not sure, or there are diffent kinds of blank values, you can try regular way:

```
df.replace('^[\s]*$', np.nan, regex=True)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you can simply do this:

```
In [217]: df
Out[217]:
  city country         id       name type year_founded
0           US  apple_inc  Apple Inc

In [218]: df = df.replace('', 'NA')

In [219]: df
Out[219]:
  city country         id       name type year_founded
0   NA      US  apple_inc  Apple Inc   NA           NA
```